# Button inside another button doesn't work in Firefox (Angular Material)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Му button (`class="patternButton"`) contains another small button (`class="patternMenuBtn"`) that should show a menu. Here is markup:

```
    <div class="patternsBlock">
        <md-button class="patternButton"
                   ng-class="{selected: view.id == selectedViewId, globalView: view.id.indexOf(userViewIdPrefix) == -1}"
                   ng-repeat="view in loadedViews" ng-click="selectPattern(view)">
            {{view.name}}
            <md-menu md-offset="26 40" ng-show="view.id.indexOf(userViewIdPrefix) != -1">
                <md-button class="md-fab md-mini patternMenuBtn" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">

                </md-button>
                <md-menu-content width="2">
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button ng-click="deleteUserView(view, $index)">
                            <span md-menu-align-target>Delete</span>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button ng-click="openViewPanel(view, $index)">
                            <span md-menu-align-target>Edit</span>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
        </md-button>
    </div>
```

Here is `openMenu`handler:

```
    $scope.openMenu = function ($mdOpenMenu, ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };
```

This works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox. Actually, `openMenu` function is not being called.

Comment: Check the value of `ev` in console...

Comment: @RayonDabre, my app never go inside this function in Firefox. So `ev` couldn't be checked.

Comment: Can you share a demo or Fiddle ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, the easiest way to check is to go to Angular Material's menu page https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/demo/menu, then at the first sample click the "Edit on CodePen" button and wrap `<md-menu>` by additional `<md-button>`. This will not work in FIrefox, but still will work in Chrome.

Comment: Why do you want to do so ?

Comment: @RayonDabre, So, the outer button represents an element of collection. Each element is associated with a set of some settings. Clicking on the outer button enables this set of settings. The inner button reveals the context menu that allows to edit or delete current set of settings. Visually it looks like big button with text and small button inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the only solution was to place buttons one next to other instead of one into other. My new markup looks like this:

```
    <div class="patternsBlock">
        <div class="patternButtonContainer" ng-repeat="view in loadedViews"
             ng-class="{selected: view.id == selectedViewId, globalView: view.id.indexOf(userViewIdPrefix) == -1}">
            <md-button class="patternButton" ng-click="selectPattern(view)">
                {{view.name}}
            </md-button>
            <md-menu md-offset="26 40" ng-show="view.id.indexOf(userViewIdPrefix) != -1">
                <md-button class="md-fab md-mini patternMenuBtn" ng-click="openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)"></md-button>
                <md-menu-content width="2">
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button ng-click="deleteUserView(view, $index)">
                            <span md-menu-align-target>Delete</span>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item>
                        <md-button ng-click="openViewPanel(view, $index)">
                            <span md-menu-align-target>Edit</span>
                        </md-button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I use CSS to make menu button appears over the main button.

Important to set `position:relative` on `patternButtonContainer` and `position:absolute` to `<md-menu>`. This way allows to put menu button everywhere you want without affecting container size.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem:

```
<md-button ng-disabled="true">
  <md-button>
  </md-button>
</md-button>
```

But i can solved with this:

```
<div class="md-button" ng-disabled="true">
  <md-button>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

Only use the css class of md-button and works correctly.